# UIWebView cookies send to Safari browser? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview, safari

For my next project i'm using a UIWebView to log into an website account, after re-opening the app the cookie is stored into the apps cookie jar and the user stays logged in.

Is it possible to send UIWebView cookies to the Safari browser cookie jar so that the user stays logged in when going to the website in Safari?

Comment: It is not possible to send the UIWebView cookies to Safari. Every app on iOS is sandboxed and the cookie jar is stored with in the sandbox. You can add an option in your app to "Sign-In on Safari". This would, if the user is already signed-in to your app, open Safari using `-[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]` with a query parameter that would set the appropriate cookies in the response.

Comment: Hmmm ok, that's what i thought. So there isn't any workaround to send cookies to Safari at all from an app?

Comment: have you find any solution for this problem? please tell me if you did it   @Jan

Comment: Any solution in the latest version please let me know